# What is the best way to plot a dict `{ "label" : [ ...dates... ], [ ...values... ] }`?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, plot

I have a dict which contains two columns for every key: list of dates and list of values

```
data = {"Key_1" : [ [ 10-1-20, 11-1-20, ...], [ 1.0, 2.1, ... ], ],
        "Key_2" : [ [ 11-1-20, 12-1-20, ...], [ 3.2, 4.1, ... ], ],
        "Key_3" : [ [ 11-1-20, 13-1-20, ...], [ 5.342, 2.124, ... ], ],
        "Key_4" : [ [ 10-1-20, 12-1-20, ...], [ 2.123, 4.321, ... ], ]}
```

sorted dates (checked). However,
When I do this

```
for l in matrix:
    ax.plot(matrix[l][0], matrix[l][1], label=l)
```

[image: I get complete mess]

What is the best way to plot my dict and why in my case lines go back on dates?

Comment: My guess is you haven't properly formatted the dates.  The "dates" in the sample data are not in a valid format.  Otherwise, you haven't provided a reproducible example, showing all the steps.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, True. Thanks for the help. But even after I did as you advice below my dates get confused and my chart look even worst. For some reason month number get confused with day number in some rows, which exactly what I was getting beforehand as well ... so my guess it is some date conversion issue?

Comment: Try changing the `dayfirst` parameter of `pd.to_datetime` (e.g. `pd.to_datetime(data[key][0], dayfirst=True)` or you can specify the `format` parameter of `to_datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a `dict` of `pandas.DataFrames`

#### Data

```py
data = {"Key_1" : [[ '10-1-20', '11-1-20'], [ 1.0, 2.1]],
        "Key_2" : [[ '11-1-20', '12-1-20'], [ 3.2, 4.1]],
        "Key_3" : [[ '11-1-20', '13-1-20'], [ 5.342, 2.124]],
        "Key_4" : [[ '10-1-20', '12-1-20'], [ 2.123, 4.321]]}
```

#### Dict of DataFrames

```py
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {key: pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.to_datetime(data[key][0], dayfirst=True),
                              'data': data[key][1]}) for key in data.keys()}

for k, v in df_dict.items():
    print(f'DataFrame {k}:\n{v}\n')

DataFrame Key_1:
       dates  data
0 2020-10-01   1.0
1 2020-11-01   2.1

DataFrame Key_2:
       dates  data
0 2020-11-01   3.2
1 2020-12-01   4.1

DataFrame Key_3:
       dates   data
0 2020-11-01  5.342
1 2020-01-13  2.124

DataFrame Key_4:
       dates   data
0 2020-10-01  2.123
1 2020-12-01  4.321
```

#### Plot `df_dict`

```py
import matplotlib.pylot as plt

for k, v in df_dict.items():
    plt.plot(v['dates'], v['data'], label=k)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]